# Not seeing my DLL function in test application

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm testing a simple DLL, I wrote using C++/CLI, in a CLR console application.  The DLL has only one function I'm trying to use.  I'm referencing the DLL and set the Resolve #using Reference in the project property page, but I cannot see the function I wrote.  I'm guessing I may have missed an access modifier somewhere, but I'm not sure.  Here is a breakdown of my code:

**DLL Code Header:**

```
// LogDLL.h

#pragma once
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System;


namespace LogDLL {

    public ref class LogFuncs
    {
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
        LogFuncs(){;};
        ~LogFuncs(){;};
        void log_to_file ( System::String ^file, bool overwrite, System::String ^text );
    };
}
```

**DLL Code Source:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LogDLL.h"
using namespace System::Globalization;

void LogDLL::LogFuncs::log_to_file ( System::String ^file, bool overwrite, System::String ^text )
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

And the test code I'm using:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#using <LogDLL.dll>
using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    LogDLL::LogFuncs^ a;
    a::LogDLL::LogFuncs:: //<-- Intellisense doesn't show the function from the DLL
    return 0;
}
```

Again, I'm not sure what I'm missing.  It's been awhile since I've worked with C++/CLI so I'm pretty rusty.

UPDATE:

I went ahead and changed the class to a struct per Peter's advice.

**Modified DLL Header Code:**

```
// LogDLL.h

#pragma once
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System;


namespace LogDLL {

    public ref struct LogFuncs
    {
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
        LogFuncs(){;};
        ~LogFuncs(){;};
        void log_to_file ( System::String ^file, bool overwrite, System::String ^text );
    };
}
```

What I still don't understand is why the class would still default to private even though I specify it as public.  Is there some fundamental reason why this is the case? Would it be any different if I was using unmanaged C++??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default access for class is private.  Either add "public:" for the members you want to be public or change to a ref struct, which has default access of public.

With respect to IntelliSense, I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio 2005 or Visual Studio 2008; Visual Studio 2010 does not support IntelliSense for C++/CLI code (this is because the parser was replaced with EDG and they didn't retrofit the C++/CLI parsing capabilities into it for 2010's release).

I doubt IntelliSense would auto-complete with the syntax you're using anyway. You'd want "a->" instead (of course, gcnew it before running this code).

Comment: Thanks Peter, I changed it to ref struct and that did the trick.

Comment: For your follow up question, the "public" on the class itself refers to the visibility of the type, not of its members.  If you had just "ref class LogFuncs", it would not be accessible outside of its own assembly.  So for a member to be accessible in another assembly in the way you desire, it needs to both be on a public type (ignoring InternalsVisibleToAttribute) and the member itself needs to be public.

Comment: Additional comment that might clear up confusion: C++/CLI attempted to meld as much of C++ as it could into concepts from the CLI (Common Language Infrastructure). As such, there are two ways of declaring a CLI class type in C++/CLI, "ref class" and "ref struct". The former behaves like a C++ class: default private access for members. The latter behaves like a C++ struct: default public access for members. The same holds true for "value class" and "value struct", except these declare a CLI value type.